# Spring throws IllegalAccessError when parsing application context file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

We're porting an application from JBoss EAP 5.1.1 to EAP 6.4.3 (AS 7.5), including upgrading Spring to version 4.1.7 and Hibernate to version 3.6.10.

When the application starts up we get a stack trace:

```
15:50:43,531 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from "/C:/default6.4/bin/content/myapp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/myapp-common-1.03-SNAPSHOT.jar/applicationContext-common.xml"; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.transaction.config.TxAdviceBeanDefinitionParser from class org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.10.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.10.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.3.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.3.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.3.Final-redhat-2]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.transaction.config.TxAdviceBeanDefinitionParser from class org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:140) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1422) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.transaction.config.TxAdviceBeanDefinitionParser from class org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler
at org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler.init(TxNamespaceHandler.java:55) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
... 31 more
```

The context.xml file contains

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="myappSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Which seems to match [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate-tx-declarative). The bean definition for myappSessionFactory is defined in a separate JAR within the same EAR.

The beans definition file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">

    <bean id="myappSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="myappDataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.myapp.Role</value>
                <value>org.myapp.Group</value>
                <value>org.myapp.UserRole</value>
                <value>org.myapp.User</value>
                <value>org.myapp.UserTask</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show.sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${myapp.schema}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Can anyone help us get past the stack trace?

Comment: please add your beans definition file, including the namespaces definition part.

Comment: @reos I've added the definition in the question.